# por que un for para cambiar los valores de una lista bajo ciertas condiciones me esta editando la lista Y sus condiciones

Tags: python, python-3.x, condiciones

El ejemplo va mas o menos asi:
Tengo las listas a y b

```
a=([1,0,1])
b=([1,0,0])
```

Genero una lista c con el mismo tamaño de las dos anteriores asi que no me importan sus datos internos, igual serán editados

```
c=a
```

Si se cumple que (a = 1 y b=1) o que (a=0 y b=0) c=1, en caso contrario c=0

```
for t in range(len(a)):
    if (a[t]==1 and b[t]==1) or (a[t]==0 and b[t]==0):
        c[t]=1
    else:
        c[t]=0
```

En teoría debería tener una lista con c=[1,1,0], y pues es cierto, el problema es que me edito también los valores de a y no entiendo por qué.

```
print(a,b,c)
[1, 1, 0] [1, 0, 0] [1, 1, 0]
```

¿Alguien me puede explicar o instruir como hacer esta operación?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Python, los datos de tipo dinamico, como las listas, se almacenan como referencias, lo que en C son punteros. Cuando dices

```
c = a
```

estas haciendo que las variables a y c apunten al mismo objeto lista. Una solucion simple es usar copy(), que te crea una lista nueva identica.

```
c = a.copy()
```

Answer (score 3):

El problema se encuentra cuando haces `c=a`, Python es un lenguaje altamente orientado a objetos. De hecho, prácticamente cada elemento de datos en un programa Python es un objeto de un tipo o clase específica.
Por ejemplo `a=([1,0,1])`, cuando haces `c=a` lo que haces es que tanto `a` como `c` apunten al mismo objeto `([1,0,1])`, por lo que debes crear una variable `c` que no apunte al mismo objeto de la siguiente manera:
`c=[0]*len(a)` con esto creas una nueva lista `c` que tiene el mismo tamaño que `a` y está llena de ceros.

Comment: Sí deseas saber más información de las variables en Python, puedes consultar el siguiente [blog](https://realpython.com/python-variables/)